# problems with memo.lines.add

Tags: string, delphi

I am trying to make a chat application that will post a message into a memo in the form like this:

```
USERNAME-> Message
```

but it is posting to my memo like this:

```
USERNAME
```

Here is my code:

```
const
  cnMaxUserNameLen = 254;
var
  sUserName: string;
  dwUserNameLen: DWORD;
  text : string;
begin
  dwUserNameLen := cnMaxUserNameLen - 1;
  SetLength(sUserName, cnMaxUserNameLen);
  GetUserName(PChar(sUserName), dwUserNameLen);
  SetLength(sUserName, dwUserNameLen);

  text:= sUserName + '-> ' + edit1.Text;
  memo1.Lines.Add(text);
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: In addition to David's answer, you might want to consider only calling `GetUserName` the first time and saving the result, since it won't change during the run of this program. Then you save the overhead of repeated calls to `SetLength`, `GetUserName` and `SetLength` again; they're only called once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value returned in `dwUserNameLen` [includes the null-terminator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And you are thus including it in the `text`. When the string is send to the Windows edit control behind the `TMemo`, the string is passed as a null-terminated string. And so the stray null from the user name terminates the data transfer.

Change the code like this:

```
SetLength(sUserName, dwUserNameLen-1);
```

You should also check the return value of `GetUserName` in case there is an error, but I will leave that detail to you.